# React-native run-android --variant=release bug (RN 57.5)

Tags: android, react-native

I can build as debug its ok but when I try to build my app as release to my android phone and I get this error.. I dont understand what is wrong about it,  I have deleted node modules and installed again, my react version is 57.5 .

```
SHA-1 for file D:\React\AEA\Index.js is not computed

ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file D:\React\AEA\Index.js is not computed
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:201:13)
    at D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:164:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:31:30)
    at D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:50:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:28:12
    at Transformer.transformFile (D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:188:7)
    at D:\React\AEA\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:78:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Well its bit strange but I have solved it like this.

in directory/index.js I was calling other Index.js file(navigations) from other directory. I changed Index.js to index.js and problem solved..